# Можно ли на котлин написать приложение для ПК?

Tags: kotlin

Начал недавно изучать котлин, стало интересно узнать про его мультиплатформенность. Насколько я понимаю на котлине можно писать одновременно под Ios и Android, а что насчёт Windows например? В интернете нашёл ссылку только на работу с вебом.

Comment: Да, можно. Точно так же как на Java.

Comment: @insolor а каким именно образом? Нужно подключать библиотеки для этого или в IntelliJ IDEA можно создать проект? Я шаблоны проектов вчера просмотрел, не нашёл ничего похожего допустим на WinForms.

Comment: WinForms - это специфично только для платформы .NET. Для Java смотрите например JavaFX или Swing.

Comment: @insolor извиняюсь за распросы, а для Kotlin есть аналоги?

Comment: ты можешь использовать явовские библиотеки в котлине

Comment: Для Kotlin можно использовать то же что и для Java. Есть библиотека TornadoFX для Kotlin, она построена на основе JavaFX, но со своими приятными плюшками.

Comment: Понял, всем спасибо за ответы!

Comment: из GUI есть ещё новый Compose Desktop

Comment: Лучше https://www.jetbrains.com/lp/compose-desktop/ но все еще можно https://tornadofx.io/

Comment: спасибо! @EugeneKrivenja